# Jetpack compose CameraX zoom

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I want to pinch to zoom, but it doesn't work. The zoom is not displayed at all. For some reason, the calculated zoom value can be greater than 1 and less than 0.9 is not lowered, although it should be in the range 0..1.

```
 val camera : MutableState<Camera?> = remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
 LaunchedEffect(lensFacing) {
       val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
       cameraProvider.unbindAll()
       camera.value = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            lifecycleOwner,
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
            imageCapture,
        )
 preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
}
```

```
 var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

 val listener = object : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            zoom = camera.value!!.cameraInfo.zoomState.value!!.zoomRatio * detector.scaleFactor
            camera.value!!.cameraControl.setZoomRatio(zoom)
            return true
        }
    }

 val scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(context, listener)
 
previewView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if(event.pointerCount == 2) {
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
}
```

```
AndroidView(
                {
                    previewView
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .matchParentSize()
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
```

I tried move camera.value!!.cameraControl.setZoomRatio(zoom) to update of AndroidView.